# Passing a property through lambda expression, and sorting on its properties

Tags: c#, generics

I have a List of ISomeType, where T contains at least one property of type IConvertibleProperty. Example:

```
IConvertibleProperty
{
    string PropertyA { get; set; }
    string PropertyB { get; set; }
    // etc
}

public class SomeTypeA : ISomeType
{
    public ConvertibleProperty PropertyX { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

I need to create a generic function, which I can call in the following manner:

```
CustomMethod(list, x => x.PropertyX);
```

And will be able to achieve next sorting in it:

```
protected void CustomMethod<T, TKey>(IList<T> list, Func<T, TKey> expr) where T : ISomeType where TKey : IConvertibleProperty
{
    // example of non-generic sorting (in this case expr = x.PropertyX)
    var sortedList = list.OrderBy(x => x.PropertyX.PropertyA).ThenBy(x => x.PropertyX.PropertyB).ToList();

    // rest of the code
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(x => expr(x).PropertyA)
                     .ThenBy(x => expr(x).PropertyB)
                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. [Here it is in action](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GksrEZ). Give the answer to Blorgbeard, since that answer was here first.

```
protected List<T> CustomMethod<T, TKey>(IList<T> list, Func<T, TKey> expr) 
    where T : ISomeType where TKey : IConvertibleProperty
{
    var sortedList = list
        .OrderBy(x => expr(x).PropertyA)
        .ThenBy(x => expr(x).PropertyB).ToList<T>();
    return sortedList;
}
```

Call it just like you asked:

```
var sortedList = p.CustomMethod(list, x => x.PropertyX);
```